# Sort collection by two different properties

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I have a class with multiple properties I want it sorted by. Currently I am sorting by `Name` like this:

```
Collections.sort(rowItems, new Comparator() {

    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        SearchRowItem p1 = (SearchRowItem) o1;
        SearchRowItem p2 = (SearchRowItem) o2;
        return p1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(p2.getName());
    }

});
```

But I also want to sort by `LastName` secondarily to `Name` (so if names are the same sort by `LastName` second). How do I combine my code below with my first sort to get the outcome I described?

```
Collections.sort(rowItems, new Comparator() {

    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        SearchRowItem p1 = (SearchRowItem) o1;
        SearchRowItem p2 = (SearchRowItem) o2;
        return p1.getLastName().compareToIgnoreCase(p2.getLastName());
    }

});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple `Comparator` that first compares the `name` and then the `lastName` will work with the `Collections.sort` method.

From the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-):

> Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

So, here is the example of the `Comparator` that compares on two properties:

```
Collections.sort(rowItems, new Comparator<SearchRowItem>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(final SearchRowItem o1, final SearchRowItem o2) {
        int compare = o1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getName());
        if (compare != 0) {
            return compare;
        }
        return o1.getLastName().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getLastName());
    }
});
```

However, there are other alternatives. Java 8 introduced streams where sorting integrates nicely. Together with the new methods `Comparator.comparing` and the `thenCompare` a nice stream can be created like this.

```
final List<SearchRowItem> collect = rowItems.stream()
        .sorted(
                Comparator.comparing(SearchRowItem::getName, String::compareToIgnoreCase)
                          .thenComparing(SearchRowItem::getLastName, String::compareToIgnoreCase))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that the latter does not sort the original `List` but creates a new sorted list.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer, it helped me really understanding sort comparing.

Answer (score 3):

If `getName()` returns 0 it means that both objects have the same name - only then should you use `getLastName()`:

```
Collections.sort(rowItems, new Comparator() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        SearchRowItem p1 = (SearchRowItem) o1;
        SearchRowItem p2 = (SearchRowItem) o2;
        int nameComp =  p1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(p2.getName());
        if (nameComp != 0) {
            return nameComp;
        }
        return p1.getLastName().compareToIgnoreCase(p2.getLastName());
    }
});
```

EDIT:
The answer above follows the OP's style. However, if possible, you should use generics to clean up the code:

```
Collections.sort(rowItems, new Comparator<SearchRowItem>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(SearchRowItem p1, SearchRowItem p2) {
        int nameComp =  p1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(p2.getName());
        if (nameComp != 0) {
            return nameComp;
        }
        return p1.getLastName().compareToIgnoreCase(p2.getLastName());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Check for equality in the first comparison

```
public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            SearchRowItem p1 = (SearchRowItem) o1;
            SearchRowItem p2 = (SearchRowItem) o2;
            int compare = p1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(p2.getName());
            if (compare == 0) {
              compare = p1.getLastName().compareToIgnoreCase(p2.getLastName());
            }
            return compare;
        }
```